# Contracted Christoffel symbol in BSSN formulation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Can someone kindly please help and explain how can obtain this equation?

$$
\Gamma^i =\gamma^{jk} \Gamma^i_{jk}= - \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\gamma}|}\partial_l \Big(\sqrt{|\gamma|}~ \gamma^{il} \Big)
$$

where $\Gamma^i = ~^{(3)}\Gamma^i$ are the 3D Christoffel symbols and $\gamma_{ij}$ is the spatial metric tensor.
The source is the book "Numerical Relativity" (Baumgarte, Shapiro), Eq. 4.40. (in this book the equation uses the 4D metric and the 4D Christoffel symbols, but in the Baumgarte video lectures he uses the above equation.)
Here BSSN is the Baumgarte-Shapiro-Shibata-Nakamura formulation.

Thanks

Comment: You have at least to explain the symbols. And it would be even more recommdable to add the source you got this equation from. But anyway, the equation must be wrong, because the indices on RHS (m) and LHS (i)  do not fit together. And BSSN is not a common abrevation "everybody" should know.

Comment: The source is the book "Numerical Relativity" (Baumgarte, Shapiro), Eq. 4.40. The correct equation is $$ \Gamma^i =\gamma^{jk} \Gamma^i_{jk}= - \frac{1}{\sqrt{|\gamma}|}\partial_l \Big(\sqrt{|\gamma|}~ \gamma^{il} \Big) $$ Sorry for the wrong index

Comment: I would recommend you to modify your post correspondingly. Still it is not clear what $\gamma_{il}$ is. Is the 4-dim. or is it the 3-dim. metric tensor ?

Comment: $\gamma_{ij}$ is the spatial metric, $\Gamma^i$ = $^{(3)}\Gamma^i$ are the related 3D Crhistoffel symbols, but I think the equation above also work for the 4-metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ using the 4D Christoffel symbols

Comment: Link to  Baumgarte video? Minute?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVbAd7kyIvQ (see at 1:07:30)

Comment: @blackhole: have you simply directly tried to compute the right hand side and compared it with the definition on the left hand side? Do you know how to relate derivatives of an inverse metric with the derivatives of the metric itself?

Comment: @Void Yes, I tried, but I couldn't do it. In particular, I don't know how to work the determinant of the metric

Comment: The BSSN formulation seems irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $\gamma_{ij}$ has signature $(1,1,1)$, so that we don't need the absolute value for $\gamma$ in your expression.
To calculate the RHS you need to use the product rule and [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) for calculating the derivative of a determinant
$$ \partial_l \gamma = \gamma \, \gamma^{ij} \, \partial_l \gamma_{ij} .$$
Using this you should get
$$  - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\partial_l \Big(\sqrt{\gamma}\, \gamma^{il} \Big) = \, ... \, = - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}} \big(\sqrt{\gamma} \, \partial_l \gamma^{il} + \gamma^{il} \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\gamma} \gamma^{jk} \partial_l \gamma_{jk} \big) .$$

Now you need to calculate the derivative of the inverse of the metric, you can do this using $\gamma^{ij} \gamma_{jk} = \delta^i_k.$
This should get you to 
$$ - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\partial_l \Big(\sqrt{\gamma}\, \gamma^{il} \Big) = \big(  \gamma^{ij} \gamma^{kl} \partial_l \gamma_{jk} - \frac{1}{2} \gamma^{il} \gamma^{jk} \partial_l \gamma_{jk}   \big) .$$
If you now calculate the LHS using the definition and the symmetry of the Christoffel symbols you should get the desired equality (be aware of matching the dummy indices).

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is clear. A last thing: in the first term of RHS in last equation, shouldn't there be a minus sign?

Comment: For the first term you will get a minus sign from the derivative of the inverse metric as well as the global minus sign leading to a plus sign for this term.