# Proof of contracting Christoffel Symbol Identity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I figured out the following:

$${\displaystyle \Gamma ^{i}{}_{ki}={\frac {1}{2}}g^{im}{\frac {\partial g_{im}}{\partial x^{k}}}={\frac {1}{2g}}{\frac {\partial g}{\partial x^{k}}}={\frac {\partial \log {\sqrt {|g|}}}{\partial x^{k}}}.}$$

However I can't figure out how to show the following identity:

$$g^{k\ell }\Gamma ^{i}{}_{k\ell }={\frac {-1}{\sqrt {|g|}}}\;{\frac {\partial \left({\sqrt {|g|}}\,g^{ik}\right)}{\partial x^{k}}}.$$

I plugged in the equation for the Christoffel Symbol but it didn't get me where I wanted. Can anybody offer clarity?

Comment: You can read this post: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/513212/

Comment: @blackhole in the answer given, he goes from the RHS to the LHS, is it much harder to go from the LHS to the RHS?

Comment: You will need the identity $\partial_a g^{bc} = - g^{bd} g^{ce} \partial_a g_{de}$.

Comment: Where does this identity come from?